# Upload to Rails Shrine from NativeScript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, mobile, nativescript, shrine

I'm using Rails 5.2 with the Shrine gem for image upload. On the client side I'm using NativeScript 6.0 with Angular 8.0.

I've installed Shrine and it's working on the Rails side and direct upload via Uppy.

On the frontend (Android mobile) using NativeScript I can take a photo (using nativescript-camera) and send it using nativescript-background-http to the nativescript-background-http demo server (node based).

The problem I have is sending from NativeScript to Shrine.

On the backend I have these routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :asset_items
  mount ImageUploader.upload_endpoint(:cache) => "/images/upload" # POST /images/upload
end
```

In my shrine setup I have

```
require "shrine"
require "shrine/storage/file_system"

Shrine.storages = {
  cache: Shrine::Storage::FileSystem.new("public", prefix: "uploads/cache"), 
  store: Shrine::Storage::FileSystem.new("public", prefix: "uploads"),           }

Shrine.plugin :logging, logger: Rails.logger
Shrine.plugin :upload_endpoint
Shrine.plugin :activerecord
Shrine.plugin :cached_attachment_data
Shrine.plugin :restore_cached_data
```

On the frontend

```
onTakePictureTap(args) {
    requestPermissions().then(
        () => {
            var imageModule = require("tns-core-modules/ui/image");

            takePicture({width: 150, height: 100, keepAspectRatio: true})
                .then((imageAsset: any) => {
                    this.cameraImage = imageAsset;
                    let image = new imageModule.Image();
                    image.src = imageAsset;
                    this._dataItem.picture_url = this.imageAssetURL(imageAsset);

                    // Send picture to backend
                    var file =  this._dataItem.picture_url;
                    var url = "https://192.168.1.4/images/upload";
                    var name = file.substr(file.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

                    // upload configuration
                    var bghttp = require("nativescript-background-http");
                    var session = bghttp.session("image-upload");
                    var request = {
                        url: url,
                        method: "POST",
                        headers: {
                            "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
                        },
                        description: "Uploading " + name
                    };

                    var task = session.uploadFile(file, request);

                    task.on("error", this.errorHandler);
                    task.on("responded", this.respondedHandler);
                    task.on("complete", this.completeHandler);

                }, (error) => {
                    console.log("Error: " + error);
                });
        },
        () => alert('permissions rejected')
    );
} // onTakePictureTap
```

The handlers look like this

```
errorHandler(e) {
    alert("received " + e.responseCode + " code.");
    var serverResponse = e.response;
}

respondedHandler(e) {
    alert("received " + e.responseCode + " code. Server sent: " + e.data);
}

completeHandler(e) {
    alert("received")
}
```

When I take a picture it tries to send it to the backend and I get the following log on the server;

```
Started POST "/images/upload" for 103.232.216.30 at 2019-08-14 11:14:09 +1000
Cannot render console from 103.232.216.30! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
```

I think the problem is in the headers I'm sending to Shrine, what is the correct way of sending the image from NativeScript to Shine?

**Update: Try multipartUpload**

I tried the multipartUpload and also got a 400 error code

```
                    // upload configuration
                    var bghttp = require("nativescript-background-http");
                    var session = bghttp.session("image-upload");
                    var request = {
                        url: url,
                        method: "POST",
                        headers: {
                            "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
                        },
                        description: "Uploading " + name
                    };

                    var params = [
                        {
                            name: "fileToUpload.jpg",
                            filename: file,
                            mimeType: "image/jpeg"
                        }
                    ];

                    var task = session.multipartUpload(params, request);
```

**Update: Try nativescript-background-http demo server

This works, I can successfully send a multipartUpload to the demo-server

**Update: middleware to log request**

Started to put together a middleware rack class to print out the response

```
class MyMiddleware
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    status, headers, body = @app.call(env)
    puts "Middleware called. Status: #{status}, Headers: #{headers}"
    [status, headers, body]
  end
end
```

When I send a file, it sends the response

```
Middleware called. Status: 400, Headers: {"Content-Type"=>"text/plain", "Content-Length"=>"16"}
```

Having a look at headers,status and body in byebug when sending from NativeScript;

```
(byebug) headers
{"Content-Type"=>"text/plain", "Content-Length"=>"16", "Cache-Control"=>"no-cache", "X-Request-Id"=>"7a5d40e2-5c09-4fc7-88b5-83813cedf20e", "X-Runtime"=>"0.055892"}


(byebug) status
400


(byebug) body
#<Rack::BodyProxy:0x000056471192c580 @body=#<Rack::BodyProxy:0x000056471192c620 @body=#<Rack::BodyProxy:0x000056471192c878 @body=#<Rack::BodyProxy:0x000056471192c968 @body=#<Rack::BodyProxy:0x000056471192cdc8 @body=["Upload Not Found"], @block=#<Proc:0x000056471192cd28@/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:16>, @closed=false>, @block=#<Proc:0x000056471192c918@/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:15>, @closed=false>, @block=#<Proc:0x000056471192c850@/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:39>, @closed=false>, @block=#<Proc:0x000056471192c5d0@/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:30>, @closed=false>, @block=#<Proc:0x000056471192c508@/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:15>, @closed=false>
```

A successful send via Uppy on the Rails side shows this result

```
(byebug) headers
{"Content-Type"=>"application/json; charset=utf-8", "Content-Length"=>"149", "ETag"=>"W/\"29040a3f35783193f7ba450aac8906bd\"", "Cache-Control"=>"max-age=0, private, must-revalidate", "X-Request-Id"=>"53b380b8-e902-49d3-885f-634fc9ea82dc", "X-Runtime"=>"0.028117"}


(byebug) body
#<Rack::BodyProxy:0x00007f2c801f8868 @body=#<Rack::BodyProxy:0x00007f2c801f8980 @body=#<Rack::BodyProxy:0x00007f2c801f8de0 @body=#<Rack::BodyProxy:0x00007f2c801f90b0 @body=#<Rack::BodyProxy:0x00007f2c801f98f8 @body=["{\"id\":\"85bf685af3b7965c701227478e2189a2.jpg\",\"storage\":\"cache\",\"metadata\":{\"filename\":\"DSCF3107_edited.JPG\",\"size\":3998332,\"mime_type\":\"image/jpeg\"}}"], @block=#<Proc:0x00007f2c801f9858@/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/etag.rb:30>, @closed=false>, @block=#<Proc:0x00007f2c801f8f98@/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:15>, @closed=false>, @block=#<Proc:0x00007f2c801f8db8@/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:39>, @closed=false>, @block=#<Proc:0x00007f2c801f8890@/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:30>, @closed=false>, @block=#<Proc:0x00007f2c801f8750@/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:15>, @closed=false>
```

Info from Chrome Network on Successful upload via Uppy

```
      - General
        : Request URL: http://localhost:9000/images/upload
        : Request Method: POST
        : Status Code: 200 OK
        : Remote Address: [::1]:9000
        : Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

      - Response                
        : Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
        : Content-Length: 141
        : Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
        : ETag: W/"8e3a470866888e1d724013e95d0a49b4"
        : X-Request-Id: 3e4222bd-e5bf-4270-bc31-1fc2c25696b1
        : X-Runtime: 0.010884

      - Request
        : Accept: */*
        : Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
        : Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
        : Cache-Control: no-cache
        : Connection: keep-alive
        : Content-Length: 110221
        : Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryBRJtv5UR0QTM2J2x
        : Cookie: _session_id=73b3a497c62bd745a789bc00b9f14361; org.cups.sid=c9eb7594a0515f4965b7a8e2f7900050; io=aArI7Q_64r2LWkc5AAAA; CSRF-Token-4MYJC=hLjA49c9bSsUhMUrYMfgSFSEnquQufo3; CSRF-Token-CAGDA=53tpJXxkvAstfeCoAKKbWgQDiQpU7xLj; CSRF-Token-TUFRR=kAWjSsQW4YCdEyGtaNKpfPT4gjToabYL; XSRF-TOKEN=HCjw%2B3WTJcSd1ddt45JGGGo8Uer43ggZZRrcsLc2NFgTdghJ852fqo0rWUx0%2FfBIOfv9YEMJ7mXw8TCix7d2cA%3D%3D; CSRF-Token-XDZDE=LyXXMXei6ci6FHrE3MfTxn3ARAKXYgMZ; _personal_property_rails_prototype_session=u65TkCvL9slUmGQQsP37lJH0BPcMw0E5%2FaDNw6frbuFw8NwqfM9gYPp%2F%2F830NFeZJqwxnYqc%2FCP%2FPIXhvPGFbD4waESKMKS1ChILCxTXZAPRFFULtu9m4Xl2G6AlF0ZamkzY7sdcE15vnpIBm8M%3D--98yhZGLNKsL5dnSX--Radl4qCShjACiTHc5UTH1A%3D%3D
        : Host: localhost:9000
        : Origin: http://localhost:9000
        : Pragma: no-cache
        : Referer: http://localhost:9000/asset_items/new
        : User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36

      - Form data
        : name: 2014-mlug.png
        : type: image/png
        : files[]: (binary)
```

**Update: Can upload through Angular using a blob**

I can upload from Angular 8.0 to Shrine using a blob.

```
sendImage(files: FileList){
    this.image = files.item(0);
    var directUrl = "http://localhost:9000/images/upload";

    // Create a formData object
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', files.item(0), this.image.name);

    // Direct Upload
    this.http.post(directUrl, formData).subscribe(event => {
        console.log("Successfully uploaded: " + event);
        this.asset.image = JSON.stringify(event);
    });
}
```

**Update: Try nativescript-http-formdata**

Here is my implementation of sending the picture via nativescript-http-formdata;

```
async sendPicture(filepath, imageAsset) {
    var url = "http://localhost:9000/images/upload";
    var name = filepath.substr(filepath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

    // Get bitmap of file
    const imageAndroidBitmap = android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath);

    // Prepare the formdata
    let fd = new TNSHttpFormData();
    let param: TNSHttpFormDataParam = {
            data: imageAndroidBitmap,
            contentType: 'image/jpeg',
            fileName: 'test.jpg',
            parameterName: 'file1'
    };
    let params = [];
    params.push(param);
    try {
        const response: TNSHttpFormDataResponse = await fd.post(url, params, {
            headers: {}
        });
        console.log(response);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
```

Error: After reviewing this error I think the okhttp3 is loaded but the syntax is wrong for NativeScript 6.0

```
LOG from device Galaxy S8: Error: java.lang.Exception: Failed resolving method create on class okhttp3.RequestBody
```

**Update: Upload via Curl to Shrine = works**

Tried the following and got the same Bad Request 400 error;

Send picture

```
  curl -X POST --form "file=@t-bird.jpg" http://localhost:9000/images/upload
   {"id":"4b4d42e77b4fa7ecddbd93cd07845cc2.jpg","storage":"cache","metadata":{"filename":"t-bird.jpg","size":1478512,"mime_type":"image/jpeg"}}
  *NOTE: when we send the picture we use 'file' instead of 'image'*
```

Send text form (optional)

```
  curl -X POST -d "asset_item[name]=curl" http://localhost:9000/asset_items.json
```

Convert output to JSON

```
  irb
  {id:"7276dc618cdd23bf3f5a9243d3c59399.jpg",storage:"cache",metadata:{filename:"t-bird.jpg",size:1478512,mime_type:"image/jpeg"}}.to_json
```

Result

```
"{\"id\":\"7276dc618cdd23bf3f5a9243d3c59399.jpg\",\"storage\":\"cache\",\"metadata\":{\"filename\":\"t-bird.jpg\",\"size\":1478512,\"mime_type\":\"image/jpeg\"}}"
```

POST text with the image data

```
  curl -X POST -d "asset_item[name]=curl" -d 'asset_item[image]="{\"id\":\"7276dc618cdd23bf3f5a9243d3c59399.jpg\",\"storage\":\"cache\",\"metadata\":{\"filename\":\"t-bird.jpg\",\"size\":1478512,\"mime_type\":\"image/jpeg\"}}"' http://localhost:9000/asset_items.json
```

**Current throughts**

I think my best chance at the moment is to use nativescript-background-http to send a multi-part post to shrine in the correct format. What ever that is.

Comment: Shrine's upload endpoint doesn't require any special headers, just a plain `multipart/form-data` file upload. The error message seems like it's coming from the `web-console` gem, though I'd be surprised if this was an actual exception and not just a warning. What is the response status of the `POST` request to Shrine's upload endpoint in the browser network tab?

Comment: At the moment all I have is "400 Bad Request" on the mobile phone. This is a NativeScript application so I don't have any form-data as the mobile doesn't have a web form. Could this be the problem? Can I send the data another way?

Comment: Ok, if "400 Bad Request" is coming from the upload endpoint, that probably means the file wasn't sent in the correct format. `multipart/form-data` is just a request body format that anyone can send, doesn't have to be a web form (e.g. `curl` can do it). The question is just whether the HTTP library you're using on the client side supports it, and it appears it does – using `multipartUpload` instead of `uploadFile` – https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-background-http#uploading-files

Comment: @janko-m Still get a 400 Bad request when using the multipartUpload. I added the code to the question

Comment: I would be great if you could find out exactly what HTTP request your NativeScript sent and what HTTP response the upload endpoint returns (at least reponse body). I’d love to help further, but at this point we need this information.

Comment: @map7 If you are able to upload using Angular blob, you should be fine with nativescript-http-formdata

Comment: For android it uses android.graphics.Bitmap

Comment: refer here https://github.com/dotnetdreamer/nativescript-http-formdata

Comment: @Narendra I've just tried that and had problems please refer to my update. I might be missing something obvious as I've tried so much now.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnetdreamer/nativescript-http-formdata/blob/92cbc5a2b19e6e776adbf091e720baac555e3db0/src/TNSHttpFormData.android.ts#L29

Comment: May be you need to modify header, I am heading off for now meanwhile you can try as per this https://github.com/dotnetdreamer/nativescript-http-formdata/issues/3#issuecomment-420184134

Comment: @map7 , I just realized this plugin has dependency and you have add that in your gradle file : // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp
compile group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'okhttp', version: '3.10.0'

Comment: @janko-m Just tried Curl and got the same issue

Comment: @map7 Here is the proof that Shrine's upload endpoint works with curl: https://gist.github.com/janko/6b902b38eaea2d0bbb2a476a1781e8b9. You'll need to see what is the difference between my example and your app.

Comment: @janko-m thanks. I did get curl working with my app and updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I managed to send an image**, the main problem I had all along was I had to set the 'name:' to "file" in my multipartUpload within the NativeScript-background-http plugin.

```
    var request = {
        url: url,
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "file-name": name,
            "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
        },
        description: "Uploading " + name
    };

    var params = [
        {
            name: "file",
            filename: filepath,
            mimeType: "image/jpeg"
        }
    ];

    var task = session.multipartUpload(params, request);

    task.on("responded", this.respondedHandler, this);
```

Once I have got a successful response from Shrine I stringified the JSON and attached that result to my data model, which later gets sent as part of my form through JSON.

```
respondedHandler(e) {
    alert("received " + e.responseCode + " code. Server sent: " + e.data);
    this._dataItem.image = JSON.stringify(e.data);
}
```

Thanks Narendra and Janko-m I didn't realise just how painful this turned out to be and as I got a greater understanding of my problem the question kept changing and I found out the real problem all along.

NOTE: I've documented my findings on the Shrine WIKI

From Curl to Shrine = https://github.com/shrinerb/shrine/wiki/Uploading-through-curl

From Angular 8.0 to Shrine = https://github.com/shrinerb/shrine/wiki/Uploading-through-Angular

From Nativescript to Shrine = https://github.com/shrinerb/shrine/wiki/Uploading-through-NativeScript-(Angular)

Answer (score 0):

As you are successfully able to upload using `blob` in your angular project. You should use `nativescript-http-formdata` plugin. You can download this from npm `tns plugin add nativescript-http-formdata` or you can find the repo [here](https://github.com/dotnetdreamer/nativescript-http-formdata).

P.S. This plugin has dependency on Okhttp, so you need to add the following in your app.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0"
}
```

Comment: I still get the same error. I've got the emulator working now and can but breakpoints in and debug. I found that nativescript-http-formdata has a 6.0 branch so I'm going to try that today.